# MacBook Air 2013 battery drained by Dropbox

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, dropbox

I just bought the new MacBook Air 13" (2013) and am experiencing dramatic battery loss when using Dropbox and a few other apps.

While that is a well know issue with Dropbox, I wonder if there is a solution for my Mac (that is build to last long time on a single battery charge).

Nico already posted [something about it](http://blog.nicoschuele.com/?p=151), and it seems Dropbox drains the battery of the new MacBook Air in about 3 hours.

That defeats the Apples design for long battery lifetime, so is there a way to I fix the Dropbox app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out (I'm the Nico from the blog post you are linking), the latest update to Dropbox corrected the issue. Now, when syncing/idling, the battery reports an insanely great remaining time.

If you have the latest Dropbox version, I'd suggest searching for other rogue processes that could drain your battery.

Comment: Thanks, Nico. By the  way, is it version 2.2.8?